# CSS Fix search box and button on header

Tags: css

I have a header with an image that would be the logo and a search bar on the right of it but the search box and the search button don't stick together

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background: white;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}

#search-bar {
  width: 60%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}

#search-button {
  width: 10%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>
    <a href="home"><img src="" alt="Company Logo"></a>
  </h1>

  <form action="search">
    <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search anything...">
    <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, how can I make the search bar and button bigger to the right while still being responsive (not wrapping, just getting smaller)?

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: white;
  }

  .header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      width: 30%;
  }

  #search-bar {
      width: 60%;
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  }

  #search-button {
      height: 40px;
      font-size: 1rem;
      border: 1px solid #D0CFCE;
      border-top-right-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  }

  .header form {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1><a href="home"><img src="" alt="Company Logo"></a></h1>

    <form action="search">
        <input type="text" id="search-bar" placeholder="Search anything...">
        <button type="submit" id="search-button">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

** You Cat Try With it **

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).